# Is it possible to get code of php function defined in eval'ed code?

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a code obfuscation system. The idea is to have a piece of php code and encrypt it and store in a text file. When executing the code, just fetch the encrypted text, decrypt it and eval it to get the functionality.

Now I am wondering if there is a way to get the function code after the eval(). I tried ReflectionFunction to get the function code but so far I could not. Is there a way to get the code of the function defined in the eval'ed code?

Comment: obfuscation is pointless

Comment: That's true. I am just trying to understand if we can get the function body code in a eval'ed code.

Comment: Obfuscation is not pointless, if you mangle variable and function names it can serve fine to make code unmaintainable by third parties. Every other form or goal of obfuscation is pointless though, and especially in your proposed situation it will be a performance killer, while regular obfuscation has no measurable effect on performance.

Comment: no obfuscation can't be undone - ergo pointless

Comment: @Dagon that's beside the point. Along those same lines password hashing, or any kind of encryption at all, is pointless because everything can be bruteforced. Obfuscation has uses to protect intellectual property if deobfuscation is more work and/or more expensive than just buying the original product or hiring the original developer. As with cryptography the goal is to make reversing the operation "practically infeasible", not "impossible".

Comment: your seriously comparing  obfuscation  with encryption?!?!

Comment: No, I'm correctly evaluating their usefulness based on the same criterium. Encryption is only useful if it takes hundreds of years to reverse it without the key. Obfuscation is only useful if it takes more time to reverse than just writing the original code yourself. Both thus depend on practical infeasibility to be useful for their separate purposes. You state that obfuscation is pointless because it can be undone, I'm merely pointing out that that argument is invalid as it also makes encryption pointless because it can be undone.

Comment: well i hope your not in charge of security .. anywhere :-;

Comment: I am, in many companies and for many online applications, because I understand these basic principles of security.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text-file it contains an encrypted `class`: how about decrypting the file, put PHP-tags around it and store it in a temp file. After that is done `include('tmp.php');` the file, remove the temp file and call the `Reflector` functionality?

Comment: Keep in mind that this will give highly unpredictable results with opcache enabled unless you take severe precautions to prevent them, effectively disabling it at runtime and thus discarding its advantages.

Comment: Of course it does :-) Another solution would be to write a customized tokenizer that 'reads' the code - or use an existing PHP-tokenizer (I can't imagine there aren't any) - if you only are interested in the _(raw)_ code.